# Facebook Game Posts With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I know how to make regular posts on a users wall from a Facebook App with Javascript but I was wondering how do you make the Game application posts with the small image to the left. I attached an image of what I'm talking about.

[preview http://www.tonygroth.com/game_app_img.png](http://www.tonygroth.com/game_app_img.png)

Comment: That is either a normal post containing a link, or (more likely) an Open Graph action published by the game. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: it can't be a normal post with a link because it says "via Car Town" and has the link for "Get Coins from Username". Regular link posts don't have those.

Comment: Oh yes, regular link posts _can_ have those! “via appname” shows up if the post is not made by the user manually, but by an app on their behalf using the API, and “get coins from” could be an _action link_.

Comment: oh, hey your right lol. I think the Open Graph link you posted would be a better solution though. thanks for the information!